# Toggle visibility of a table element HTML through a button

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I am writing a XSL file which transforms a piece of XML into HTML and it contains a snippet of javascript code that I use to toggle the visibility of an table element HTML by a click on a button. I don't need to use style at the moment.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='myXSL.xsl'?>
<LISTS>
  <SCR>repository</SCR>
  <Dependency><ArtifactId>maven</ArtifactId>
  <GroupId>NO</GroupId>
  <!--two tags details appear only if the 'GroupId' node value  is 'NO'-->
  <detail1>
    Here is a text detail 1
  </detail1>
  <detail2>
    Here is a text detail 2
  </detail2>
  </Dependency>
  <Dependency>
    <ArtifactId>eclipse</ArtifactId>
  <GroupId>YES</GroupId></Dependency>
</LISTS>
```

My XSL is:

```
<xsl:template match = "/">
 <html>
   <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle(p1,p2)
    {
      if(document.all){document.getElementById(p1).style.display =
   document.getElementById(p1).style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";}
      else{document.getElementById(p1).style.display =  
   document.getElementById(p1).style.display == "table" ? "none" : "table";}
      document.getElementById(p2).value =  
   document.getElementById(p2).value == "[-] Detruire" ? "[+] Construire" : "[-] Detruire";
     }

    </script>

   </head>

     <BODY>
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="LISTS/Dependency">
                <xsl:call-template name="myTemplate"/>      
            </xsl:for-each>  
        </table>
     </BODY>
 </html>
 </xsl:template>

<!-- called template-->

<xsl:template name="myTemplate">
<tr>        
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="GroupId='YES'">
         <tr>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="ArtifactId"/></td>
             <td>OK</td>
        </tr>
         </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="GroupId='NO'">
        <tr>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="ArtifactId"/></td>

            <td align="right">KO<input id="mylnk" type="button"  
   value="[+] Construire" onclick="toggle('tb','mylnk');"/></td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 
                <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="4" 
    cellspacing="0" id="tb" name="tb">
                  <tr>                   
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="detail1"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="detail2"/></td>
                 </tr>     
                 </table>
            </td> 
        </tr>              
        </xsl:when>

    </xsl:choose>
</tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result I get with my XSL is below:

[image]

How can I change my XSL to get by default this one?

```
![enter image description here][2]
```

And when expanding, getting this one?

```
![enter image description here][3]
```

Comment: just to check, set display block using inline style at the table and the code `document.getElementById(tbid).style.display =
   (document.getElementById(tbid).style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";` is enough to see if the display is toggling

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you say to do. Please could you please tell me exactly what,where I have to replace into the visibility function and with what i have to do that? Thanks

Comment: I have posted an answer, run that and see if it works! also if it doesn't work give `document.getElementById("+tbid+")` a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is to make the table collapsed by default on page load, add the below to your table tag (with id=tb):

```
style="display:none;"
```

Comment: Taking account your answer, this part of code becomes <tr>
<td><table style="display:none;" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" id="tb" name="tb"><tr><td><xsl:value-of select="detail1"/></td>    <td><xsl:value-of select="detail2"/></td></tr> </table>. Problem is that the "[+] Expand" value of button is not toggling. Indeed there is no reaction at the click event on this button. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console? I find that it works fine even with the code you has posted in your comment above.

Answer (score 0):

```
function visibility(tbid,lnkid)
{

   document.getElementById(tbid).style.display =(document.getElementById(tbid).style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
   document.getElementById(lnkid).value =(document.getElementById(lnkid).value == "[-] Collapse") ? "[+] Expand" : "[-] Collapse";
 }

</script>


<table width="100%" id="tb" name="tb" style="display:block">
```

also give the format...

```
getElementById("+tbid+")
```

a try